# Compound Interest Quarterly 2

Tags: calculus, economics

> You want to buy a car that costs $250,000$ USD. To finance the
>   outstanding debt you wan to take out a loan, which you have to pay
>   back by quarterly payments over $7$ years. The first payment is due one
>   quarter after you took out the loan.  The interest is $6$ % p.a.
>   compounded quarterly.
>
> Calculate now the quarterly payment

My answer:

$FV=PV*(1+\frac{r}{n})^nt= 250 000*(1+\frac{6\%}{4})^4*7 = 250 000*(1,015)^28= 379 305$  --> pays back

Just divide it by $28$ to find the quarterly payment

$\frac{379 305}{28}=13 546.6$

Is it right? Would apreciate any help

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

The debt gets compounded then the rate subtracted, 
$$
D_{n+1}=D_n(1+\tfrac r4)-R
$$
which is a simple linear recursion with general formula
$$
D_n-\tfrac{4R}r=(D_0-\tfrac{4R}r)(1+\tfrac r4)^n
$$
To get $D_{28}=0$ you will need
$$
0=D_0-(1-(1+\tfrac r4)^{-28})\tfrac{4R}r
$$
resulting in the perhaps more familiar rate formula
$$
R = \frac{\frac r4D_0}{1-(1+\tfrac r4)^{-28}}=11000.269118957289
$$

Comment: Hi LutzL. Are you sure, that it is a right answer? It is total different than some tutorials I have seen about Compound Interest. Thanks anyway for your effort and time

Comment: Then link one such tutorial. The math is correct. I might be wrong in the interpretation of your data.

Answer (score 0):

The effective quarterly rate is $i=\frac{i^{(4)}}{4}=\frac{6\%}{4}=1.5\%$. The number of payments is $n=4\times 7=28$ and the loan is $L=\$\,250,000$.

Then the quarter payment is
$$
\boxed{
P=\frac{L}{a_{\overline{n}|i}}=\frac{\$\, 250,000}{22.73}\approx \$\,11,000.27
}
$$
where $a_{\overline{n}|i}=\frac{1-(1+i)^{-n}}{i}$.